# More elegant way of creating Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe

I need to create a DataFrame out of some arrays - one (`allReturns`) which is size n x m (i.e. two dimensional), and others (`allID`, `value`) which are simply n x 1 (i.e. one dimensional). At the moment I am doing:

```
allReturnColIdx = np.arange(np.shape(allReturns)[1])
df = PA.DataFrame(data = allReturns, columns = allReturnColIdx)
df['allID'] = allID
df['value'] = value
```

And then when I want to read the `allReturns` values out I have to do something like:

```
df[allReturnColIdx]
```

There must be a better way of doing this where I can create the DataFrame in one line and be able to refer to all my returns in one go instead of having to resort to a numerical index (`allReturnColIdx`).

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear to me. In fact, there seems to be two questions and neither seem to be much of an issue, that would be preventing your code from working, so I'm not quite clear on what the trouble is. But I'll try to answer what I understand from what you wrote.

First, you're asking how to create the DataFrame in one line. I'm not sure from your example why that's necessary.  The four lines you have are pretty clear. And if no columns are provided, the np.arange() is the default to create indexing. So I believe if you omit that code for the index, it's cleaner:

```
df = PA.DataFrame(data = allReturns)
df['allID'] = allID
df['value'] = value
```

Looks as good as one line of code to me.  In addition, the [DataFrame constructor](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) could take 'arrays, constants, or list-like objects' including dicts. So if you insisted, you could jam all of those into one single line; it would be arguably less readable.

Then, your second question asks about access. The DataFrame has [all kinds of indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html).

Specifically, for your example, you're always appending two columns; then you are wanting to access them in some more convenient way? to me, that's a good use case for the .iloc indexing.

```
df.iloc[:,:-2]
```

The above line returns all the rows of the DataFrame, and all but the last two columns. Which I think is what you're asking for.

Here's a chunk of code that I used to verify everything I wrote. Hope it helps. If this wasn't what you were looking for, I suggest you clarify your question.

```
all_returns = np.random.randn(6, 4)
df = pd.DataFrame(all_returns)
print df
df = pd.DataFrame(all_returns, columns=np.arange(np.shape(all_returns)[1]))
print df

all_id = np.random.randn(6,1)
value = np.random.randn(6,1)

df['all_id'] = all_id
df['value'] = value
print df

print df.iloc[:,:-2]
```